# SQL DATEADD/WHERE syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I'm having some trouble with my WHERE statement complaining. I've declared a variable called @StartDate with a datatype of DATE since I don't want the time. I'm going to be updating a temporary table multiple times based on how many orders were placed in the last 30, 60, 90, etc days, but doing it in separate statements.

```
    UPDATE #TempTable SET Q30Day = Count(*)  
    FROM #TempTable
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -30, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
    WHERE PaidTime >= @StartDate
```

The WHERE statement is complaining, saying 'INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR 'WHERE'' but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Could it be that you have 2 `SET` clauses in the query? Perhaps that second part should be done first and then the `update` can be a single query that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just got things muddled up and in the wrong order:-

```
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -30, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))    
UPDATE #TempTable SET Q30Day = Count(*)  
FROM #TempTable
WHERE PaidTime >= @StartDate
```